# Learning with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull data form a website and have been looking and trying to learn for weeks. I'm trying

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

req = requests.get('http://www.rushmore.tv/schedule')
soup = Soup(req.text, "html.parser")

soup.find('home-section-wrap center', id="section-home")
print soup.find
```

but it's returning something do to with Steam that's completely random considering that nothing I am doing is related to Steam.

```
<bound method BeautifulSoup.find of \n<td class="listtable_1" height="16">\n<a href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198134729239" target="_blank">\n        76561198134729239\n    </a>\n</td>>
```

What I'm trying to do is scrape a div ID and print the contents. Extremely new. Cheers

Comment: Which URL are you scraping?

Comment: Can you may let us know what the url you're using here is? Maybe it is related to Steam, even if you didn't expect it to be like that.

Comment: The URL is http://www.rushmore.tv/schedule. The data I am trying to scrape is the schedule Data. I believe the ID of the div i am trying to scrape is "id="myUL"

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://www.rushmore.tv/schedule')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

for row in soup.find('ul', id='myUL').findAll('li'):
    print(row.text)
```

Partial Output:

```
10:30 - 13:30 Olympics: Women's Curling, Canada vs China (CA Coverage) - Channel 21
10:30 - 11:30 Olympics: Freestyle, Men's Half Pipe (US Coverage) - Channel 34
11:30 - 14:45 Olympics: BBC Coverage - Channel 92
11:30 - 19:30 Olympics: BBC Red Button Coverage - Channel 103
11:30 - 13:30 Olympics: Women's Curling, Great Britain vs Japan - Channel 105
13:00 - 15:30 Olympics: Men's Ice Hockey: Slovenia vs Norway - Channel 11
13:30 - 15:30 Olympics: Men's Ice Hockey: Slovenia vs Norway (JIP) - Channel 21
13:30 - 21:30 Olympics: DE Coverage - Channel 88
14:45 - 18:30 Olympics: BBC Coverage - Channel 91
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run following code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

quote_page='http://www.rushmore.tv/schedule'
def page_scrapper(quote_page):
    print(quote_page+' is being processed... ')
    page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page) #Let's open the page...
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser') #And now we parse it with BSoup parser..
    box = soup.find('ul', attrs = {'id': 'myUL'}) #Save the contents of the 'ul' tag with id myUL(it contains schedule)
    print(box) #and print it!
page_scrapper(quote_page)
```

This should do the trick.

EDIT - added some lines of code

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm getting 
File "<stdin>", line 7
    page_scrapper(quote_page)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax..

I love figuring stuff out. I'll get there eventualy:)

Comment: could you please tell python version you are using?

Comment: Currently 2.7 as I couldnt get Bsoup to install on 3+